# Simplification rule not being applied properly

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima, computer-algebra-systems

I'm trying to use Dirac Bra-Ket notation in Maxima using the code from here http://raoul.koalatux.ch/sites/ladderoperator/ladder_operator.html

```
declare(bra, nonscalar);
declare(ket, nonscalar);
dotscrules:true;
matchdeclare(m,lambda([t],featurep(t,integer)));
matchdeclare(n,lambda([t],featurep(t,integer)));

tellsimp(bra(m).ket(n), kron_delta(m,n));
```

For most expressions it works:

```
bra(0) . ket(0);
ket(1) . bra(0) . ket(0);
bra(1) . ket(1) . bra(0) . ket(0);
```

all simplify correctly, but

```
bra(1) . ket(1) . bra(0);
```

fails to simplify to bra(0).  How can I get Maxima to simplify this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can start with this:

```
declare(bra, nonscalar);
declare(ket, nonscalar);
dotscrules:true;
matchdeclare(m,lambda([t],featurep(t,integer)));
matchdeclare(n,lambda([t],featurep(t,integer)));

tellsimp(bra(m).ket(n), kron_delta(m,n));

simp:false;
matchdeclare(aa, true);
matchdeclare(bb, true);
matchdeclare(cc, true);
tellsimp (aa.(bb.cc),(aa.bb).cc);
simp:true;

/* Tests */
bra(0) . ket(0);
ket(1) . bra(0) . ket(0);
bra(1) . ket(1) . bra(0) . ket(0);
bra(1) . ket(1) . bra(0);
ket(1) . bra(1) . ket(1);
```

Comment: Excellent, that works, but why do I need to redefine the associativity of `.` ?

Comment: I think `.` is not associative. Consider this example `[a, b]: [[1, 0], [0, 1]];
a . (b . b);
(a . b) . b;`

Comment: From the manual: Option variable: dotassoc 
Default value: true 
When dotassoc is true, an expression (A.B).C simplifies to A.(B.C).